# Eclipse: Unknown tags on new line

Tags: eclipse, angularjs

I'm using custom tags for HTML (using AngularJs). I want the formatting in eclipse to look like the below:

### Expected:

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading='Series'>
        something
    </tab>
    <tab heading="Input Controls">
        something
    </tab>
    <tab heading='Options'>
        something
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

### After formatting in eclipse

```
    <tabset> <tab heading='Series'> something </tab> <tab heading="Input Controls"> something </tab> <tab
                heading='Options'> something </tab> </tabset>
```

Everything is forced to the single line.

> How to control the flow of unknown elements/tags in eclipse?

Thanks,

Comment: My first guess is that eclipse formatting tool works with standard HTML tags, so I guess that it gets confused with Angular. Isn't there any plugin or something for angular? But I am not sure that that would help.

Comment: I don't think it make sense since you can create with directive whatever you want, and for sure, you can't change Formtter on any new directive.

Comment: Although not an answer to our question, a workaround for just now is to format in an external tool such as a website such as the following: http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html

Answer (score -1):

You could also open your file in the `XML Editor` instead of `HTML Editor`. It would probably format your tags well.

Comment: Thanks. Tried opening in XML editor, but still the formatting is same as HTML editor.

Comment: @sowdri Have you tried to open it on the XML editor and then format/indent your code? Ctrl+Shift+F or Select all code+Ctrl+I?

Comment: Yep, I tried that, but there is no difference in the formatting of HTML editor and XML editor. Somehow XML editor also treats the known html tags differently from the unknown ones. Surprising, but true.